# Integer number too large (android / java)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Declaring int constant like

```
 private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 0909;
```

this would result into "Integer number too large"

while   `private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1909;` works fine why would the android studio suggest that 0909 is too large but 1909 is fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, numbers with a leading `0` are treated as *octal* numbers. Octal numbers are base 8 and use the digits `0` through `7`, while the digits `8` and `9` are not valid.

To declare a decimal constant, use:

```
private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 909;
```